# how to unindent in vim without leaving edit mode?

Tags: vim

I'm writing a lot of python code recently, and i used the tab-to-space mode in vim. I was just wondering how would i unindent in vim without leaving edit mode for example after i finished if...: block. Normally I can just type << to unindent, but it takes too many keystorkes, anyone have a better idea?

Comment: Put these lines in your .vimrc, and you will be using 4 spaces instead of TAB character, with <TAB> key indenting and <BACKSPACE> key unindenting properly. set tabstop=4 set shiftwidth=4 set expandtab set smarttab set cindent

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> on your keyboard, removes one tabstop at a time, works for space-replaced tabs.

Comment: It does work on gVim running on Windows. Not sure if it works somewhere else.

Comment: for multiline I would switch to the visual mode "shift-V", highlight the lines and use the < and > symbols to change indentation.

Comment: It appears all useful commands in edit mode are kind of like emacs style.

Comment: If anyone is like me and wants to know how to indent the line whilst in Edit mode (at any point in the line) you can type `Ctrl`-`T`. Help for these operations when in insert mode can be found with `:help i_CTRL-D`

Answer (score 37):

In Vim in Linux you can unindent multiple lines by using `V` to select your first line. Press the down arrow to select multiple lines. Then type `<` to unindent all of the lines.

If you want to indent, type `>` instead

Comment: This works outside of edit mode. Though it is factually correct, it is not an answer to the stated question.

Comment: While it's true this doesn't answer the question, this is the first link on Google about unindenting in general (so it has my upvote)

Answer (score 3):

Backspace will remove one level of indent at a time.

Comment: It seems backspace doesn't work on Vim in Windows, does it need some configuration?

Comment: This depends on what options you have set.

Comment: I believe (correct me if I'm wrong) that it depends on your `'backspace'` option (check with `:set backspace?`). Mine is set to nothing (just `backspace=`), and the backspace key doesn't work for me. Possibly fiddling with that option (check out `:help 'backspace'`) could allow you to backspace over the indentation.

Comment: Why can't it just be SHIFT-TAB like in any other reasonable editor?

Answer (score 1):

You can press `Ctrl-U` it will delete backwards to the beginning of line.